# Array Loop start from Middle

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have the following array:

```
$alphabet = array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g")
```

If I wanted to begin from **"d"** and loop through the array to be outputted as `d,e,f,g,a,b,c`.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Thing is, will there always be 7 in the array, or will start from the 4th position in the array? Or is that not important? There are too many ways to do this.

Comment: yes there will be always 7 in the array  but it wont always start from the 4 position.

Comment: You're going to have to update your question to be clearer on that. I might not be able to help, but others might be able if they knew exactly what it is you want to achieve. Edit: and if there will always be uneven numbers in the array, or will the eventually be even sets?

Comment: there will be even sets. anyway thanx for the help. I got the answer

Comment: I just tried it with a even set. it worked without a problem

Comment: Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) function to achieve what you want:

```
<?php
$alphabet = array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g");

// find the index of the start element in the original array
$index = array_search("d", $alphabet);

// iterate the array from starting point to the end
foreach (array_slice($alphabet, $index) as $value) {
    echo $value, ",";
}

// iterate the array from the very beginning to the starting point
foreach (array_slice($alphabet, 0, $index) as $value) {
    echo $value, ",";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$alphabet = array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g");
$startIndex = 3;// index of d
$count = count($alphabet);
for($x = 0; $x < count($alphabet); $x++){
    $index = $x + $startIndex < $count  ? $x + $startIndex :  $x + $startIndex -  $count;
    echo $alphabet[$index];
}
```

outputs

> defgabc

see [live demo](https://eval.in/1072783)

if you don't know the index of the element you want you can use `array_search`

```
$startIndex = array_search('d', $alphabet);
```

Comment: thanx for the answer. but How can I print defgabc

Comment: sorry didn't notice that in the question, fixed it

Comment: thanks for the answer. I got the answer earlier. but I up voted your answer