# How to iterate over an array from a particular key?

Tags: php

How to iterate over an array from a particular key?

example:

```
$days = ['Dimanche','Lundi','Mardi','Mercredi','Jeudi','Vendredi','Samedi'];
```

I'd like to start on Wednesday (`$key 3`) and loop until Tuesday (`$key 2`)?

Comment: If I understood you correctly. Start your array on Wednesday and end on Tuesday. Then go through with a `foreach ($i=3; $days as $key => $value) { echo $key . '' . $value . '' . $days[$i]; $++; }` loop. I hope this helps

Comment: I think it depends on the array, do you know where to start by key or value? Is always the same number of items? I think this link should help you getting started https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53953251/array-loop-start-from-middle

Comment: Thank you very much, it was exactly what I've searched since hours!

Answer (score 0):

here is an ugly solution.but if you want.you can wrap it as a function.
but I want to know the situation you meet.then maybe solution the problem by another way.

```php
$days = ['Dimanche','Lundi','Mardi','Mercredi','Jeudi','Vendredi','Samedi'];

$start = 3;
$end = 2;
$len = count($days);
while(true){
    print_r($days[$start]."\n");

    if($start==$end) break;
    $start++;
    if($start>=$len) $start=0;
}
```